# SP 2013 - People search result - Access Denied

Tags: search-results, people-search

People result throws access denied for regular users. I cant remember where to go and grants right for read only for user profile or people crawl. What do I need to do?

Comment: is anybody else able to access the people search Results? did you see the crawl log, if crawler able to crawl the people repository? May be you need to add the default content access account into User Profile Adminsitrator.

Comment: I dont know why i can't reply to waqas comment. But I can see the people result with their pictures. but my account is in the farm admin account.

Answer (score -1):

I added domain users to the visitors group of the search site and access denied is gone. Thanks